# Drawing a plane from equation

Tags: 3d, shiny

I wrote a code with Shiny but now I got stuck on a thing and I just have to ask.

In the code you will see that on the "server" side I want to plot a plane from an equation. But I got this: 
http://www.onlinemathe.de/forum/Ebenen-Gleichung-durch-2-Winkel

Its in German, but on the end you see an example which leads me to my equation.

The problem is it first just draws a point in 3D instead of a plane!

Second, is there a better way to tell R that it should use the data from my `data.frame`, row by row?

I thought like in MATLAB something like:

```
data[i,1] and data[i,2]

i+1
```

Here's the code, please help me if possible!

```
install.packages("shiny")
install.packages("rgl")
install.packages("plotrix")

library(shiny)
library(rgl)
library(plotrix)

ui <- fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Block Theory 0.1"),
    sidebarPanel(
        numericInput(inputId = "strike", label = "Strike:", value = "", width = "80%", min = 0, max = 360),
        numericInput(inputId = "dip", label = "Dip:", value = "", width = "80%", min = 0, max = 90),
        actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "Add a plane"),
        actionButton(inputId = "plotbutton", label = "Update")
    ),
    mainPanel(  
        rglwidgetOutput(outputId = "plot")
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "log_planes")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data_planes <- data.frame()
    makeReactiveBinding("data_planes")  

    observe({
        input$add
        isolate({
            data_planes <<- rbind(data_planes, data.frame(input$strike, input$dip))
            data_planes <<- na.omit(data_planes)
        })
    })  

    output$plot <- renderRglwidget({
        input$plotbutton
        isolate({
            if (i < nrow(data_planes)) {
                phi <- 90 - data_planes[1,1]
                deta <- data_planes[1,2]

                a <- sin(phi)*cos(deta)
                b <- sin(phi)*sin(deta)
                c <- cos(phi)

                planes3d(a,b,c,d = 0)

                i <<- i + 1
            }
            rglwidget() 
        })
    })
    output$log_planes <- renderPrint({print(data_planes)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: This part realy doesnt work:
     isolate({
      if (i < nrow(data_planes)) {
        phi <- 90 - data_planes[1,1]
        deta <- data_planes[1,2]

        a <- sin(phi)*cos(deta)
        b <- sin(phi)*sin(deta)
        c <- cos(phi)

        planes3d(a,b,c,d = 0)

        i <<- i + 1

It should plot  "planes" in 3D using data sets (each row) of the data.frame :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Do you get an error, or are the results not what you expect? Add this information in your post, we can't read your mind :-)

Comment: I did an EDIT :)

Comment: Cristina :) ? (Können auch deutsch reden ^^)